# Compare a String with a Char in C

Tags: c

I'm having an issue with this:

```
char procNames[10][80];

[...]

strncpy(procNames[i], readedLineFromBuffer, 80);
```

On readedLineFromBuffer only enters one char.

Then I want to compare another char that I input by stdin with the chars that I stored in procNames.

So, for example, I have:

```
procNames[0]: A
procNames[1]: B
procNames[2]: C
```

And, by stdin buffer (named `line` in my program) I write `IS B INSIDE` or `IS C INSIDE`, `IS <CHARACTER> INSIDE`...

So I get `line[3]`, that will be the B or C character, and I want to check if `line[3]` is stored in procNames.

I do the following:

```
for(int strgName = 0; strgName < processNumber; strgName++) {
    if(strncmp(line[3], procNames[strgName], 1) == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "MATCH: %s\n", strgName, procNames[strgName]);
        isInsideProgram = true;
    }
}
```

But the `strncmp()` throws segfault. How do I compare what is inside `procnames[10][80]` (that is a character) with `line[3]`? I've tried with `strcmp()` and `line[3] == procNames[strgName]` but it throws segfault too...

Edit: It was solved by comparing `line[3] == procNames[strgName][0]` thx a lot!

Comment: `strncmp` request pointers to char, you give `char`, if you want to check two `char` are equals just use `==` with them

Comment: `line[3] == procNames[strgName] but it throws segfault too...` are you sure *processNumber* is the right limit of index for *procNames* ? also 3 for *line* ?

Comment: `procNames[0]: A` that is incompatible with `char procNames[10][80];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line[3]` is a `char`, but the first two arguments to `strncmp()` must be `char *`. You could use `&line[3]`.

But simpler is to just compare the characters directly:

```
if (line[3] == procNames[strgName][0])
```

Comment: It doesn't enter inside the loop, idkw

I've made change it to: line[3] == procNames[strgName][0]

And added this to check: fprintf(stdout, "%d: id-%c proc-%c\n", strgName, line[10], procNames[strgName][0]);


The output is:

0: id-B proc-A
1: id-B proc-B
2: id-B proc-C

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and see why.

Comment: @bruno I interpreted that to mean `proc_names[0]: "A"`

Comment: @bruno The code in the question shows how he fills in `proc_names[i]` with `strncpy()`, so I thought it was pretty clear, and didn't concern myself with the way he presented that table of values.

Comment: @sanz_sual At first you said it didn't solve the problem. What changed?

Comment: This was surprisingly throwing another sigfault: `fprintf(stdout, "MATCH: %s\n", strgName, procNames[strgName]);` it has 2 variables to print in one placeholder, I'm so dumb that I didn't realize about it

Comment: @sanz_sual nobody saw, including me ^^ Probably your compiler signaled that no ? Next times try to give in your question the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that means a program we can compile and run. Doing that we would have been able to compile your program and to detect that extra argument. Always take into account the message produced by the compiler, ask it to be verbose about warning/error, for instance if you use *gcc* compile with at least the option `-Wall`. [Barmar sorry for using your answer to put remark for OP]